# Using Laplace transforms to solve a convolution of two functions

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, partial-fractions

Hi I have this problem where I need to take the convolution of functions and I am not sure if I got the right answer or something close so any advice or help would be very appreciated. So here is the problem.
$$t^{2} * e^{-2t}= L^{-1}(L(t^{2} * e^{-2t}))$$
$$=L^{-1}(L(t^{2}) \cdot L(e^{-2t}))$$
Which is:
$$=L^{-1}((\frac{2}{s^{3}})(\frac{1}{s+2}))$$
$$=L^{-1}(\frac{2}{(s^{3})(s+2)})$$
Then I did partial fractions to solve this:
$$\frac{2}{(s^{3})(s+2)}=\frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s^{2}} + \frac{C}{s^{3}} + \frac{D}{s+2}$$
Then I solved for the unknown coefficients and got this:
$$\frac{2}{(s^{3})(s+2)}=\frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s+2}$$
Then we take the inverse Laplace transform of this:
$$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s+2})= 1- e^{-2t}$$
So my answer would be that $$t^{2} * e^{-2t}= 1- e^{-2t}$$
Now I am not sure if this is the correct answer or the most efficient way of solving a problem like this so any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you state the original problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. Using Laplace Transforms followed by Partial Fractions is probably the best way to solve this problem. (The next easiest way would be to evaluate $\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)^2e^{-2\tau}\,d\tau$).

When doing the partial fractions, you should have gotten:

$\dfrac{2}{s^3(s+2)} = \dfrac{\tfrac{1}{4}}{s} - \dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2}}{s^2} + \dfrac{1}{s^3} - \dfrac{\tfrac{1}{4}}{s+2}$.

Check your work on that step.